# Merge Tuples that are nested in List of Lists [Haskell]

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to merge:

```
[[('a',False),('b',False)]]
with
[[('a',True)],[('b',True)]]
```

and get the following:

```
[[(a,True),(b,True),(a,False),('b',False)]]
```

Essiently merging the two lists tuples into one.

I tried to create a function to do this but I'm not getting the output I want. Here's my current function and the output it gives me

```
mergeFunc :: [[a]] -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
mergeFunc xs [] = xs
mergeFunc [] ys = ys
mergeFunc (x:xs) ys = x : mergeFunc ys xs

[[('a',True),('b',True)],[('a',False)],[('b',False)]]
```

It seems that I'm merging a level higher than I want to, but I'm not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Why are these lists of lists? What happens if there are other sublists?

Comment: That's how they've been given. Could you give an example of what you mean by other sublists?

Comment: What if the first sublist is `[[('c',False)],[('d',False)], [('e', False)]]`?

Comment: hmm, as it currently stands I'm only trying to work with sublist lengths of 2. The Lists are produced when performing logical and/or functions to inputs. So the first List in my example came from an 'and' operation and then the second came from an 'or' operation.

Comment: but exactly how does the two sublists reflect in the result of the function? It seems like you concatenate all elements, and then add these to a new singleton list.

Comment: Yeah your right, that's just the output I've been asked to give.

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate the sublists together in one list with [**`concat :: Foldable f => f [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:concat):

```
mergeFunc :: [[a]] -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
mergeFunc xs ys = [concat xs ++ concat ys]
```

and this will produce:

```
ghci> mergeFunc [[('a',True)],[('b',True)]] [[('a',False),('b',False)]]
[[('a',True),('b',True),('a',False),('b',False)]]
```

But then it makes not much sense to wrap the list in a singleton list. In that case it makes more sense to define this as:

```
mergeFunc :: [[a]] -> [[a]] -> [a]
mergeFunc xs ys = concat xs ++ concat ys
```

since this removes an unnecessary list level.